# Property [count] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

estoy trabajando una funcion para insertar datos de un archivo excel hacia una tabla de mi BD (usando Excel MaatWebsite).

La logica es asi: mi archivo excel tiene 2 columnas con X valores cada una, el archivo lo cargo desde una ventana modal que ademas trae unos datos adicionales que se deben insertar, entonces en una "Tabla Padre" inserto ciertos datos, y en la "Tabla Hija" inserto los datos del excel junto con el ID de la tabla papa...Todo va bien y hace el insert pero me muestra este error: Property [count] does not exist on this collection instance.

Mi funcion es la siguiente:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $data = Excel::toCollection(new SerieImport, request()->file('serie'));
        $rows = $data[0];
        //dd($rows);
        $contador =0;

        $serializacion = new Serializacion();
            $serializacion->fecha_serializacion = $request->get('fecha_serializacion');
            $serializacion->user_id = $request->get('user_id');
            $serializacion->ingreso_material_id = $request->get('ingreso_material_id');
            $serializacion->save();

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $contador+=1;

            $det = new DetSerializacion();
            $det->mac = $row[0];
            $det->serie = $row[1];
            $det->status = $request->get('status');
            $det->material_id = $request->get('material_id');
            $det->serializacion_id = $serializacion->id;
            $det->save();
            //Alert::success('Registro Añadido con exito!!!', 'Las Series han sido almacenadas con exito...');
            //return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Expediente actualizado correctamente');
            //dd($det);
            }
            //return response()->json(["status"=>$contador]);

        if ($data->count > 0) {
            foreach ($data->toArray as $key => $value) {
                foreach($data as $row){
                    $insert_data[] = array(
                    'mac' => $row['mac'],
                    'serie' => $row['serie'],
                    //'serializacion_id' => $row['serializacion_id']
                    );
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

El insert lo hace bien en ambas tablas...

Saludos a todos

Comment: ¿Cuando haces `$data->count` quieres el conteo de los elementos o quieres acceder a una propiedad `count` que existe ahi?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo tienes mal escrito debe ser:

```
$data->count()
```

Edit:

Para que nuestro amigo @JuanRivera este contento agrego el link de donde dice que `count()` se escribe con paréntesis ya que es una `collection` que necesita contar:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-count

Comment: Seria bueno dejar la referencia correspondiente para que sea util para todos

Comment: A que te refieres con "dejar la referencia correspondiente"?   @JuanRivera

Comment: El link de la documentacion donde aparece eso, que se escribe asi

Comment: @JuanRivera te refieres a esto: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-count ??

Answer (score 0):

El error que te dice *Property [count] does not exist on this collection instance* es por el contenido de $data, es una colección, puedes usar el metodo [toArray](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html#importing-to-array-or-collection)

`$data = Excel::toArray(new SerieImport, request()->file('serie'));`

con lo que tienes directamente un array y modificar tus foreach finales ya que ahora no tiene sentido la conversión a array

```
if ($data->count > 0) {
    foreach($data as $row){
        $insert_data[] = array(
        'mac' => $row['mac'],
        'serie' => $row['serie'],
        //'serializacion_id' => $row['serializacion_id']
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: En si estaba mal escrito `$data->count`, porque deberia ser `$data->count()`